# Javascript toggle function

Tags: javascript, toggle

I am currently using the following code on a website to allow some div's to be populated with content via ajax when a link is clicked, as well as hidden again if clicked a second time.

The javascript function that does this is (stripped of irrelevant code):

```
function showNews(id){
    if(CONDITION){
        ajax(); //Not actual code, original code just grabs content via ajax and puts it into an existing empty div using innerHTML.
    }
    else if (CONDITION) {
        document.getElementById('div'+id).innerHTML = ''; // Empties div again, in effect hiding it from view.
    }
}
```

This currently works fine, as when each link is clicked the corresponding DIV fills with content, and when clicked again the content disappears. However, I can open as many of these div's as I want at the same time. I want it to work so that when a new div is populated the rest are emptied.

All of the div's have an ID like this: id="div#" where the # is replaced with a unique ID number.

So I need to do something like this:

```
function showNews(id){
    if(CONDITION){
        ajax(); //Not actual code, original code just grabs content via ajax and puts it into an existing empty div using innerHTML.
**FOR ALL DIVS THAT HAVE AN ID THAT STARTS WITH 'div', BUT DOES NOT MATCH CURRENT ID VARIABLE, SET innerHTML = ''**
    }
    ... code removed from original ...
}
```

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: So... what's your question? It seems like you have a handle on the logic.

Comment: I had the logic figured out, just not sure the best way hide a bunch of DIVs without knowing the  for each of them, and only knowing that the ID would start with 'div'. For example, <div ID='div123'>.

Got it sorted out now, the accepted answer works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName('div')` is an array (a node list, actually) of all divs.

You can check their IDs with `.id`.

Try this:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
    if( (divs[i].id.substr(0,3) == 'div') && (divs[i].id != ('div' + ID)) )
        divs[i].innerHTML = '';
```

`divs[i].id.substr(0,3) == 'div'` checks if the div's `id` is `divSomething`.

`divs[i].id != ('div' + ID)` makes an exception for `divID`.

Comment: I was starting to get somewhere before you made your post. I got it to hide all DIV's except the current one. Only problem, it was hiding ALL DIV's, so navigation and everything.

Your solution works perfectly, and is a bit faster than what I was doing as well.

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could give each div the same name (because names, unlike Ids, do not have to be unique) then use document.getElementsByName to find & clear them prior to populating the current div.